# Issue in left join using dplyr package: Error in left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y, check_na_matches(na_matches))

Tags: r, join, dplyr, left-join

I am trying to left join using `dplyr` package in R.

```
Join_data <- left_join(df1, df2, by.x = c("Paid"),  by.y = c("Price"))
```

The error message says

> ```
> Error in left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y, check_na_matches(na_matches)) : 
>   Can't join on 'Disposition' x 'Disposition' because of incompatible types (factor / logical)
> ```

I have thoroughly checked both fields `Paid` and `Price` are integers.

Comment: try by= c('Paid'= 'Price') and not the by.x and by.y. the dplyr readme states: `To join by different variables on x and y use a named vector. For example, by = c("a" = "b") will match x.a to y.b.`

Comment: Price side has NA values which cannot be removed (as per the requirement)

Comment: @Linus: It worked!! Thanks

Comment: You may want to share the sample data using `dput(df1)` & `dput(df2)` so that others can reproduce the same error and helps you in right direction. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) link might help you update your post.